# Office Excel macOS not filling arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, office365, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to work with arrays in Office's Excel(update 16.16.1) on macOS(High Sierra). However simple filling does not seem to work. 
I tried the following simple check to see what is happening:

I select a horizontal range of 4 cells, using "Ctrl + U" I type:

```
={1,2,3,4}
```

Then I press "CMD+ Return" and the result comes out as:

```
1    1    1    1
```

Instead of "1    2    3    4".. I also tried using ";" instead of "," but the same result comes up. When I check the contents of the filled cells it has simply copied "={1,2,3,4}" into every cell. I thought the result of the filled cells should look like "{={1,2,3,4}}".

It think it probably has to do with some language setting or something similar, but I can't figure out what setting or where to look.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It's Ctrl+Shift+Return to array-enter a formula.

Comment: Tried this, but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: You should see `{={1,2,3,4}}` in the formula bar if you entered it that way.

Comment: It does copy/fill when I enter {={1,2,3,4}} and then press Ctrl+Shift+Return but it then just displays "{={1,2,3,4}}" in all of the 4 cells, instead of the actual values.

Comment: No, you do not enter that. You type `={1,2,3,4}` and then press Ctrl+Shift+Return. You should then see `{={1,2,3,4}}` in the formula bar.

Comment: Ah thanks! The order in which I did the steps appeared to be wrong. 
What I did was: type "={1,2,3,4}" then select the 4 cells and try to fill using Ctrl+Shift+Return.
The correct order was: select 4 cells, type ={1,2,3,4}, and then press Ctrl+Shift+Return..